# Rewrite an uri to another uri without changing the address

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to *rewrite* http://www.mydomain.com/catalog/signup/newsletter to http://www.mydomain.com/newsletter with the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^newsletter$ /catalog/signup/newsletter [P,L]
```

This works on our development server but not in production. Our host has pointed out that `[P] (Proxy)` should only be used for `absolute URLs`, not `local URIs`.

I would like the address to reflect http://www.mydomain.com/newsletter and **not** *301-forward* to the other, longer, URI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try your Rule without the [P] ?

Try your rule with this param : [QSA,L]

Comment: Yes. If I remove the [P] the rule isn't applied.

Comment: Try with this param : [QSA,L]

Comment: Unfortunately QSA does not work. Seems like the rule is not applied at all.